# Is it possible to use a MOS 6502 with a AE29F2008?

Tags: memory, interface, processor

I wanted to buy a MOS 6502, but before that, wanted to know if it is possible to interface it with an AE29F2008 memory (recovered from a PC). The problem is that the AE29F2008 has three address pins more than the MOS 6502. Does anyone know if it's possible in theory?

If it's not possible, does anyone know other memory that I can use or another MOS processor to use with the AE29F2008?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some discussion on the subject [here](http://forum.6502.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=5403&start=90). It looks like it should work. Generally you can use a memory IC with more address lines than the CPU, you can just pull all of the extra ones low or use them for bank switching.

What are you planning to use it for? Since it's a Flash memory you'll probably need some RAM as well, and probably I/O, so you'll need to come up with a memory map and address decoding.

That IC is 2 Mbit, or 256kB x 8, so it should have address pins up to A17 where the 6502 goes to A15. That should be two extra address lines, not three.

Comment: Thank you for the link.